# Error duplicating data when scraping from Web to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am looking for your kind help on my coding to pull data from Web to Excel.

Web to get data:

https://eport.saigonnewport.com.vn/Pages/Common/Containers_new

- Steps to get data:

Put "Cát Lái" to field "Khu vực giao nhận container" (choose seaport)

Put container number to field "Container"

Deselect "Chỉ vòng luân chuyển cuối" to show all rows in data table

Click Search to show data table - result for searching Container information

> ISSUE:
>   Data scraped from web to Excel for each row in Excel (respective to
>   each container number found) seems to be the same with the previous
>   result WHILE information for this container number can be blank. For
>   example: Event time 2 "10/4/2020  3:07:00 PM" is repeated for
>   container "TEMU3311320" while this container does not have Event time
>   2.

Hope you could give me any advices to resolve this duplicating issue. Attached Excel file for your references. Thanks.

```
Sub PullDataFromWeb()
  Dim IE As Object, W As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Dim lastRow As Integer, b As Boolean, tmp As String
  Dim lis, li
  Set W = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set IE = VBA.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True   'hien cua so IE
  IE.navigate "https://eport.saigonnewport.com.vn/Pages/Common/Containers_new"
  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4      'doi IE chay xong
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
  Loop
  Set doc = IE.document

  lastRow = W.Range("B" & W.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2).End(xlUp).Row        'dong cuoi cung trong cot B container
  If lastRow < 2 Then GoTo Ends
  On Error Resume Next
  For intRow = 2 To lastRow     'tu dong toi dong
    b = False
    b = W.Range("I" & intRow).Value Like "[Yy]"
    If W.Range("B" & intRow).Value <> "" And Not b Then
      doc.getElementById("txtItemNo_I").Value = W.Range("B" & intRow).Value 'so cont
      doc.getElementById("cbSite_VI").Value = W.Range("A" & intRow).Value
      doc.getElementById("chkInYard_I").Checked = False
      doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSearch").Click 'click Search
      '----------------------------------------------
      Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
      Loop
      '----------------------------------------------
      strFindContainer = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder2_lblNotice").innerText
      W.Range("H" & intRow) = strFindContainer
      If strFindContainer Like "T*m th*y * container*" Then
        strEventtime1 = doc.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow0").Cells(0).innerText
        strEventtype1 = doc.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow0").Cells(1).innerText
        strLocation1 = doc.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow0").Cells(2).innerText
        strEventtime2 = doc.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow1").Cells(0).innerText
        strEventtype2 = doc.getElementById("grdContainer_DXDataRow1").Cells(1).innerText
        W.Range("C" & intRow) _
          .Resize(, 5).Value = Array(strEventtime1, strEventtype1, strLocation1, _
                         strEventtime2, strEventtype2)
      End If
    End If
  Next
Ends:
  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing    'Cleaning up
  Set objElement = Nothing
  Set objCollection = Nothing
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before that last `Next` make sure you assign all relevant string vars to `vbNullstring` i.e. those in `Array(strEventtime1, strEventtype1, strLocation1, strEventtime2, strEventtype2)` as it is inside an `If` then when `If` not met prior values will be retained in later loop iterations.